# Assembly Language Code issue

Tags: assembly

I am learning Assembly language on my own time and trying to solve the following problem. I wrote the code, but it will not work.

> Write a program that uses a loop to calculate the first seven values of the Fibonacci number sequence described by the following formula: Fib(1) = 1, Fib(2) = 1, Fib(n) = Fib(n -1) +Fib(n-2).

I need this program written in Assembly language. Use the comments in the program template as instructions to write the code in Assembly language. I would like the program to be written in Assembly language following this programming logic:

```
.data
;declare an array 
.code
main proc
;move 0 into ebx to initialize
;move 1 into edx to store the first Fib value
;move edx into an array ; store the first Fib value

; prepare to loop
; loop counter for 6 more values
; move esi,4
; array index for 3rd Fib value

L1:
;move ebx into eax
;add edx and eax
;move edx into the array of esi
; eax = ebx 
; eax = eax + edx 
; store the Fib value
;move edx into ebx
; prepare for next iteration
;move eax into edx
;add 4 to esi
;Loop  L1

invoke  ExitProcess,0
```

my code:

```
ExitProcess PROTO

.data

numbers DWORD 10 DUP (?)

.code
main PROC
    mov ebx,0
    mov edx,1
    mov numbers,edx

    mov ecx,6
    mov esi,4

L1:
    mov eax,ebx
    add eax,edx
    mov esi,OFFSET numbers
    mov [esi],edx
    mov eax,ebx
    add eax,edx
    mov edx,ebx
    mov eax,edx
    add esi,4
Loop L1

    call ExitProcess
main ENDP
END
```

I edited my code to the following:

```
ExitProcess PROTO

.data

numbers DWORD 10 DUP (?)

.code
main PROC
    mov ebx,0
    mov edx,1
    mov numbers,edx

    mov ecx,10
    mov esi,4
    mov esi,OFFSET numbers

L1:
    mov eax,ebx
    add eax,edx
    mov [esi],edx
    mov ebx,edx
    mov edx,eax
    add esi,4
    Loop L1

    call ExitProcess
main ENDP
END
```

When I step through the code, the eax register and edx register will show the Fibonacci sequence values: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, etc. However, does the code store the eax register or the edx register value in the numbers array? If not how do I do this.

Is this a valid line of code? Does it store the edx value in the numbers array?

```
mov numbers,edx
```

How do I store the eax or edx value in the numbers array?

Comment: Stack overflow is not a “please give me teh codez” kind of website.

Comment: Next time don't remove comments when you fill in your code. Maybe you can compact them a bit, but keep them around for reference and debugging.

Comment: `mov numbers,edx` is valid in MASM (TASM emulating MASM too). It compiles to `mov DWORD PTR [ds:OFFSET numbers],edx` (verbose technical way to describe it exactly). It's valid, but confusing and fugly, because it's hiding the `[]` (memory access) from reader of source! Your new edit in question is almost correct, with slight catch, if you will debug it and watch the memory and `esi` values, and compare it with `OFFSET numbers`, you will soon fix it, you are close.

Comment: BTW, there's other alternative way to write those values, to use `esi` as index/offset (not address) into `numbers`... then `mov esi,4` between makes sense (that's offset to `numbers[1]` element)... and the write instruction is then `mov numbers[esi],edx` (not sure if I hit MASM syntax), that's like `mov [OFFSET numbers + esi],edx` and that hopefully makes sense?

Comment: How do I see the values for the `OFFSET numbers` ? When I debug, I have a watch list so I can see the register values, I have a memory window open so I can see the values in the array. I do not know how to watch the `OFFSET numbers` change. Do you mean watch the `esi` value change, because I pointed the array to `esi` ? I think I just see the memory address change by 4 bytes for the `esi` value.

Answer (score 0):

Some of problems in your code:

```
mov esi,OFFSET numbers
mov [esi],edx
```

This will init `esi` ahead of each write, so you will be overwriting the element "numers[0]" all the time.

```
mov eax,ebx
add eax,edx
mov edx,ebx
mov eax,edx
```

This doesn't make much sense... first you calculate `eax = ebx+edx` ... second time (eax already contains that value from previous lines).

Then you do `eax = edx = ebx;` (ie. you copy ebx into both eax and edx)
You probably wanted to do it the other way around, like: `mov ebx,edx mov edx,eax`.

That "move esi,4" from original comments make little sense, it would make some sense as `add esi,4`, would you already had `numbers` address in `esi` (like the next code does).

But it looks like you didn't understand what address is, so in "store the Fib value" you load the address again and again. The whole point is to set `esi` only once to the start of the array, and then update the pointer after each write to point to next free space.

---

Overall get some debugger and start to watch the registers and memory step by step after each instruction, compare it with each instruction description, until it will get familiar to you, what they do, it looks from the code you have no clue what those instructions actually do.

---

And now try to understand this:

```
    mov   esi,OFFSET numbers  ; esi = target array address
    mov   ecx,7    ; produce seven numbers
    xor   ebx,ebx  ; ebx = 0 F(-1)
    mov   edx,1    ; edx = 1 F(0)
    jmp   store_number
loop1:
    add   ebx,edx  ; ebx: F(n) = edx: F(n-1) + ebx: F(n-2)
    xchg  ebx,edx  ; ebx: F(n-1), edx: F(n)
store_number:
    mov   [esi],edx ; array_pointer[0] = F(n)
    add   esi,4     ; ++array_pointer
    loop  loop1
```

Also note how many instructions are doing the pure paper formula work ("F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)"), and "7 numbers" and how many instructions are there just to support the thing. You may disagree, but I would say that cca. 50% is "support cruft", most of it is direct paper -> code rewrite.

Keep that in mind when learning assembly, make sure you have first very clear idea what you want to achieve at formula level, then try to do *that* ... add support code only when absolutely necessary. Don't write just some random instructions around, because it looks like good idea or you wrote it like that before. Instruction either "does something particular you want", or cut it out.

---

edit on comment:

`mov esi,OFFSET numbers` stores address of symbol "numbers" into `esi`. It's not important if you declared `numbers` as `BYTE` or `DWORD`, the address points at the first location (first byte) of memory allocated.

The byte/dword/dup is important to allocate enough total space, but doesn't affect the address itself ("symbol").

`mov [aaa],vvv` stores value "vvv" into memory at address "aaa" (check instruction guide to see the possible combinations).

So `mov [esi],edx` right after `mov esi,OFFSET numbers` will store every value at "numbers[0]". Look in debugger, how `esi` is getting reset every time by that `mov esi,OFFSET numbers`.

And please don't use quirk syntax `mov numbers,edx`, that stores value into "numbers" array only in MASM (and TASM when emulating MASM quirk mode), in proper Intel syntax the usage of `[]` signals dereferencing of pointer/address, so it's easy during reading source to tell, whether the instruction operates with register/immediate value only, or if it does access memory. (`lea reg,[address]` is exception, that doesn't access memory, only calculates the address). In NASM the `mov numbers,edx` would not compile at all, and `mov edx,numbers` would not load first value from array, but the address itself (in MASM/TASM you have to write OFFSET ahead of symbol).

So

> "does the code store the eax register value in the numbers array?"

No, it overwrites only first `numbers[0]` value.

Comment: ExitProcess PROTO

.data

numbers DWORD 10 DUP (?)

.code
main PROC
 mov ebx,0
 mov edx,1
 mov numbers,edx

 mov ecx,10
 mov esi,4

L1:
 mov eax,ebx
 add eax,edx
 mov esi,OFFSET numbers
 mov [esi],edx
 mov ebx,edx
 mov edx,eax
 add esi,4
 Loop L1

 call ExitProcess
main ENDP
END

Comment: When I step through the code, the eax register will show the Fibonacci sequence values: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, etc. However, does the code store the eax register value in the numbers array? If not how do I do this.

Comment: @ISM34 while you step through code, open also memory view, and move it to the address of "numbers", so you can immediately watch how the memory values change upon each write. ( **"But it looks like you didn't understand what address is"** - still holds true)